# Typo3 template changes are not taking effect

Tags: html, caching, typo3

I have a website that is managed by typo3. I modified the alt-text of the site logo in my template (index.html) . Much to my surprise the changes did not take any effect in the frontend. I also deleted the cache but nothing happened?

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Which templating engine ?

Comment: If you are using templavoila as your template engine, you have to update the mapping

Comment: I'm not asking for TYPO3 ver, but templating engine used in your project, i.e. have you got TemplaVoila running?

Comment: Yes. TemplaVoilà is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every change in template mapped by TemplaVoila must be confirmed by TemplaVoila module. Click it, find the folder with templates and click "Update Mapping" for template(s) marked by yellow warning sign.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've modified the correct template (there can be several templates for a page) by viewing the page's TypoScript object browser and verifying that the desired value actually exists.

If that doesn't help there's probably a mistake in your TS and you should show the relevant portions of your template.